A redesign of a bulky 12 kV source
I’m a low voltage electrical prototype designer. Currently I’m working with a client that had a circuit that transforms 240 VAC (50Hz) to around 2400 V. After that they use a Cockcroft Walton ladder to boost it up to 12 kV. They use the voltage in an air filter and the current through the filter is about 10 uA.
My question is, is it possible to utilize high frequencies to generate and regulate the final voltage and making it controllable in some sense?
This is just an investigation in plausability to provide the client with a new path forward.
The issues with todays setup are:

Bulky and expensive transformers
Fixed output voltage
A lot of bulky capacitors

Or how would any of you tackle this issue?
And again, I’m not after a detailed schematic but more the building blocks of knowledge on how to pitch an alternative solutions.

As stated, I’m not going to do the job just get enough knowledge to find the right guy. And sorry if the question isn’t for this forum, I’ll check other sources. Thanks for the reply though!

@Andyaka It would be better to help people edit their question instead of chasing them off.

I’m not going to modify the question since it states all that I’m currently wondering about. Marcus and jpa have provided excellent answers on what to study in order to start looking for the right person for me.

@JohanKarlsson I was an original Stack Overflow contributor. Your question is objective and well formed: members can evidently answer your question; it's upvoted and even hot network listed. However certain spinoff Stack Exchange sites suffer from "gatekeeping" from high-rep members who are often very knowledgeable but are dismissive of new members asking what they perceive as a "trivial" question. Instead of being constructive and asking to reform the question, they will tell you to remove the question and/or to contract the job out. Welcome, thanks for the Q, and please take no heed.

Thanks @rab! Really great answers!

As the one with the answer: let's still not demonize Andy, shall we? I can fully understand that if someone gets the feeling, hey, this is really over the asker's head, that it's sometimes the appropriate response to tell them that hm, maybe they are wrong to sell that as a service. Now, here that was a misinterpretation. Happens. Andy is usually super helpful, I'm sure he wouldn't want you to leave, Johan. Sorry you got the irritated side of anyone here – I've been guilty of that myself, but strive to improve myself.

Absolutely, but I’m not going to sell my design as a service but rather point them in the right direction forward. I’m a mediocre low voltage electronics guy but an awesome programmer and generic tech problem solver. I’ve learned a lot from the answers and do take high voltage seriously.

You might consider mechanical means for generating high voltage DC, such as a charge carrying belt or disk.  That way, no high voltage rectifier is required.  Do they still make the 1B3 vacuum tube?


Currently I’m working with a client that had a circuit that transforms 240 AC (50 Hz) to around 2400 V. After that they use a Cockcroft Walton ladder to boost it up to 12 kV.

Sounds a lot like a setup you find in classical consumer TVs with a cathode ray tube display, for the acceleration voltage.

They use the voltage in an air filter and the current through the filter is about 10 uA.

Just out of my own curiosity: 1.2·10⁴ V · 10⁻⁵ A = 100 mW

My question is, is it possible to utilize high frequencies to generate and regulate the final voltage and making it controllable in some sense?

Yes, you "just" need to close the feedback loop; your voltage multiplier might not exactly multiply with a known factor, but we can be certain that "more input voltage" means "more output voltage".
So, sounds to me like you want to build a flyback SMPS controller, which generates your "intermediate" voltage (currently, 2400 V), but whose voltage feedback, with which its decides whether it has reached the desired output voltage, is fed from the output of the voltage multiplier, not directly from the output of the transformer.

Because you can't let your intermediate voltage become too large, you'll probably want to still measure that voltage, and signal "too much voltage" to the controller when either case sets in, with a simple comparator / diode-OR solution:

the intermediate voltage exceeds safe limits
the target voltage reaches the desired value


Flyback controllers are a dime a dozen at larger PMIC manufacturers, like TI, onsemi etc. You probably want to have something with a constant switching frequency in this application (makes feedback design easier, see below).
because the phase of the current through the C-W multiplier might be very hard to predict precisely, your feedback path might be as easy as taking large-value resistors to divide the output voltage down to something "safe" (say, 2.048 V) and comparing that with a simple comparator against a reference voltage (e.g. as generated by a DAC, to make things adjustable!).
Or you might need to add some phase-shift network.

Of course, if that's easier, you could also avoid the "tight" coupling of the high-voltage output to the intermediate voltage control. Instead, you could have start your controller such that by default it aims at the lowest sensible output voltage (according to a one-time manual calibration). Then, your microcontroller samples the high voltage, and adjusts the reference for the intermediate voltage such that it reaches the target voltage. The question here is which adjustment speed and stability you need – you're building an outer control loop with a larger time constant; and usually, these are more annoying to design than control loops where an action (like, changing the time current flows through a transformer) has an effect very shortly after. However, seeing you're competing with something steered, not controlled, and rippling at 50 Hz, I think a simple, slow, PID controller might really do here.

Alternatively: You keep the intermediate voltage constant. But instead of just letting the AC at 50 Hz drive the capacitor ladder of the C-W multiplier, you rectify that (can use the current transformer setup, or buy or build an isolated flyback SMPS); then use an H-Bridge to build an inverter, i.e., to switch the polarity at the input of the C-W fed from that intermediate voltage.
You can then use smaller capacitors, because nothing forces you to switch at a low frequency. To get electrical charge from low potential to high potential, you can either charge large capacitors a few times per second, or small ones a lot of times!
Note that usually, efficiency goes down a bit when you increase switching frequency in capacitor banks – simply because of the higher losses. But you're not doing "insane" voltage multiplication here.
You can then adjust the output voltage by loading the output with a capacitor (which you usually inherently do, so nothing to be done here, potentially), and adjusting which percentage of time your H-bridge conducts current at all.
The main difference to the first approach is that the controlled switching here happens after the transformer, whereas above it happens at the input of the transformer.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I have been working on a hi-pot tester that goes up to 4 kV at 200 µA.
The basic setup is like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The flyback transformer raises the voltage to about 1 kV. The zener diodes on its input clamp the voltage to avoid frying the MOSFET in no-load conditions.
The diode multiplier then raises the voltage to target level. To monitor the voltage, a resistor chain drops the voltage to a level measurable by ADC. The resistor chain also balances the voltage across the output capacitor chain. The high voltage load is spread across multiple parts in order to be able to use commonly available components.
A software control loop then adjusts the PWM frequency to achieve the target voltage. In practice I have found the output voltage to be within 2 %, with ripple of a few volts. The accuracy is limited by the resistor chain, which could be calibrated as needed.
High voltages like this require significant isolation distances if left unpotted. For easy potting, I used only SMD parts, so the potting compound could be poured on the PCB with a simple 3D printed frame. For a prototype it is a good idea to have enough isolation distance that the board can run unpotted. In my case the high voltage board is about 100 x 100 mm with 2 mm isolation distances. These are enough to avoid immediate arcing, but wouldn't prevent long-term creepage/tracking.
Note that by itself this schematic does not have any isolation between supply and high-voltage output. This could be achieved by ensuring enough isolation in the transformer and using isolated ADC for feedback.
(I have a more complete schematic here, but it has complicating factors like two-sided output and current measurement. I have built working prototypes but it should be regarded as experimental.)

+1, and: interesting aspect about the isolation. I guess the adjustability makes this harder than the usual off-line isolated supply, whose "ADC" really is a "1 bit diode forward voltage converter" in an optocoupler. I guess having the DAC in the high-voltage domain and just feeding back the 1 bit "treshold crossed" information is probably easier than an isolated ADC – the DAC would probably be adjusted very rarely and hence can use an arbitrary slow transport, whereas the speed of comparison with the reference voltage would is relevant (for a tight loop; I don't think you're doing this here).

@MarcusMüller I agree. In my case I needed the current measurement also, so ADC was a necessity. For 12 kV isolation the components get harder to find, even the transformer might have to be custom-wound. On the other hand it depends on application if isolation is needed or just passive current limiting is enough.
